# "a essa altura do campeonato..." How can we explain its usage to a non-native speaker?

Tags: expressões-idiomáticas, uso-mais-comum

If you explain it means "depois de tantos acontecimentos", one who is learning Portuguese as a foreign language may come up with "a essa altura do campeonato o povo acaba/acabou ficando anestesiado" or, worse, "a essa altura do campeonato eu nem vou trabalhar amanhã".  Then again, if you say it means "tarde demais", you may hear them say something like "Eu cheguei a essa altura do campeonato" or "Encontrar às 11 da noite? Para mim é a essa altura do campeonato."

To explain that "a essa altura do campeonato" means "depois de tantos acontecimentos" or "tarde demais" is an easy task.  However, how can we explain its usage?

EDIT
In addition to definition and examples, the answer I'm looking for should explain usage.  Something like "use it if the context is such..." and "don't use it if the context simply..."

EDIT II
Not everyone seems to understand what I'm looking for.   The answer to my question must include definition of "a essa altura do campeonato", example sentences and. most important, why one uses it, what's the implied mood? (surprise? anger? hopelessness? none of these?)

Comment: Eu cheguei a essa altura do campeonta means tarde demais??

Comment: @Lambie   Those are wrong uses of "a essa altura do campeonato" as examples of what a student might come up with if his teacher only tells him that the idiom means (as it really does) "tarde demais" or "depois de tantos acontecimentos".

Comment: I think you should provide sentences in Portuguese instead of trying to tell us how to translate it. I gave three examples in my answer, they are all correct. It doesn't necessarily mean: depois de tantos acontecimentos. It can refer to any process. And it means: this/that point in time OR at this stage of the game.

Comment: @Lambie  The answer to my question must include definition of "a essa altura do campeonato", example sentences and. most important, why one uses it, what's the implied connotation?  (surprise? anger? hopelessness? none of these?)

Comment: We say sample sentences not example sentences. And I gave you what I consider to be the three main meanings. It appears to me that you are more interested in not getting an answer than actually getting one.

Comment: This idiom doesn't always mean "it's too late". It is often used to describe the current (or the expected) state of affairs of something that has already started long ago. For instance, a teacher during the middle of the semester may tell his students that they should already be familiar with such and such material which has been covered numerous times already: "A esta altura do campeonato, vós já deveis estar confortaveis com esta matéria."

Comment: @proofromthebook A esta altura do campeonato, vós já deveis estar confortaveis com esta matéria. RIGHT=At this point or At this stage of the game, you should be comfortable with this subject. Just as I said in my answer.

Comment: uma matéria que um estudante estuda se chama subject em inglés e não material.

Comment: Em US english material está correcto.

Comment: No, it is not right. Educational materials are books, handouts, tapes, programs, whatever.  But, ***estudar uma matéria na escola*** is ***to study a subject in school***. Not a material. É falso amigo. Acho que não tem jeito de tirar o gato do poço. Até logo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love explaining topics to students by providing some examples, show your friend some examples so that they will get it easier. I know how hard it is to try to learn a language by single words, it sucks. I get it much easier by seeing an example than being taught by a professional.

Here are some examples that I made up of conversations including that expression:

- *Philip:* Hey, bro! How is life going?
- *You:* It is falling apart!
- *Philip:* Why?? Have you lost your job?
- *You:* No, worse! My girlfriend and I have recently argued and she decided to move to Italy. I love her so much, I wish she were here.
- *Philip:* So, why don't you go there and bring her back? You have a car, maybe you still reach her!
- *You:* Nah! *A essa altura do campeonato*, she must be about 1000 KMs away from here.
- *Philip:* It's never too late!

Comment: Giving examples is sure to make it easier.

Comment: There are some unidiomatic things here....just saying. Also, I don't see any explanations and why mix the two languages? How does that explain the expression?

Comment: That's a good example but you don't explain when the idiom can be used and why it fits your example but not mine.

Comment: It can be used in any situation, according to the example I gave. You could explain to him that _A essa altura do campeonato_ means "_by now_" . Show him these examples, but replace the part where I said: _Nah! A essa altura do campeonato she must be.._ for: _Nah! By now she must be.._ so that your friend will know where it is used. It can replace the "by now", so when your friend is confused about using the expression, ask him to replace the expression for: _by now_, if it fits well, then the expression will also work.

Comment: Also, it's most commonly used in tragic or frustrating situations, such as my example.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: Centaurus, please, resume what you really want to know, do you want to know how to explain to  a non-native the differences between those expressions and when to use them? I can't understand your question very well, although I have already read it 3 times, maybe if you increase some ponctuation in your question, it will be easier for me to understand. And if possible, rewrite everything in Portuguese so I can understand better. I'm native, if you write it in Portuguese, maybe I get your point.

Comment: @DavydDiniz  O que eu espero encontrar na resposta:  1. O significado de "a essa altura do campeonato"  2.  Em que contextos a expressão é usada.   3. Qual a conotação e o humor de quem fala  (sarcasmo?  decepção?  raiva? surpresa?)  e  4. exemplos.

Comment: @Centaurus - I guess I have already answered all your questions, look at my first 3 comments, I explained what are the possible meanings for this expression in English, when it's mostly common used  (what situations). But I'm gonna rewrite them, by order, in   the below comment.

Comment: As I presume my answer wasn't clear enough, I'm going to rewrite them more explainable: _*1-Significado de "A essa altura do campeonato":* Isso pode ser um pouco complicado de ser entendido por não-nativos, mas eu vou tentar encontrar a palavra que é mais parecida com seu significado: *"By now", "Right now", "After it all"*. Ela significa esses 3 termos em contextos dramáticos e trágicos (como já mencionado)._ *2 - Em que contexto ela é usada:* É normalmente usada em contextos que expressam arrependimento, momentos trâgicos, angústia e tristeza ou até em piadas ou contextos engraçados.

Comment: *3-Qual a conotação (raiva, sarcasmo tristeza..)*: Eu acho que a segunda resposta responde essa, mas tudo bem. A expressão pode ser usada em diferentes contextos, inclusive em todos que você citou, veja alguns exemplos: _Eu briguei com ela ontem, e ela se mudou para Italia, e a essa altura do campeonato ela deve estar a 1000 KMs longe daqui._ - _Ontem, os assaltantes que roubaram à loja foram levados para à prisão dos Estados Unidos de avião para serem julgados, a essa altura do campeonato eles já devem estar sendo julgados._.

Comment: _Meu pai morreu semana passada, a essa altura do campeonato ele deve estar no céu_ - _O governo prometeu construir 10 edifícios para abrigar os necessitados há 3 anos atrás, a essa altura do campeonato pelo menos 5 já devem ter sido construidos._ Esses são alguns exemplos que eu pensei, espero que tenha ajudado, desculpe pelo formatamento, estou usando o aplicativo do celular, é bem difícil formatar texto por aqui. Aqui está um grau de formalidade e informalidade para usar esta expressão: _Formal:_ 30%. _Informal:_ 100% (Pode ser usado em qualquer conversa informal). See ya.

Comment: Esses últimos exemplos poderiam ter sido incluídos na tua resposta.  E o tom da expressão, eu entendo que mais frequentemente ela transmite um tom de frustração por ser tarde demais para se fazer alguma coisa.

Comment: Exactly, Centaurus; just like I said in a previous comment: *Tais expressões significam esses 3 termos em contextos **dramáticos** e **trágicos***

Answer (score 2):

We say in English: at this stage of the game, as a generic expression. We also just use, at this point/at that point or specifically: at this time?

A essa altura do campeonato can be any one of those, depending on context:

For example: 
1)A essa altura do campeonato, o nosso namoro terminou.
Translation: At this stage of the game, our [girlfriend-boyfriend] relationship ended.

2)A essa altura do campeonato, pedi desculpas e sai de casa.
Translation: At that point, I said I was sorry and left the house.

Essas são as dois jeitos mais comuns de usar essa expressão.

3) [uma festa] Você só está chegando agora, cara? A essa altura do campeonato?
Translation: Man, you're only getting here now? At this hour?

Comment: "a essa altura do campeonato"  refers to the time you are speaking.  If you refer to a past event, you'd use "naquela altura do campeonato" or, not so usual, "àquela altura do campeonato".  Also, it doesn't simply mean "at this point in time".  You can't simply say "a essa altura do campeonato eles já chegaram no aeroporto" to mean "at this point" unless it has been said that now it's too late to do whatever should have been done.

Comment: @Centaurus Claro, pode se no passado também. I said: at this or that point in time, didn't I? A essa altura do campeonato, ele já chegou em casa (falando no presente). At this point in time (in the present), he has already arrived at home.

Comment: I have never heard anybody use "a esta altura do campeonato" in such circumstances, and I don't believe any native portuguese speaker (from Portugal at least) would say it. I would never use "a esta altura do campeonato" to describe an immediate action.

Comment: @proofromthebook "in such circumstances"? What circumstances. I gave three different examples in Portuguese with three correct translations. What is an immediate action anyway?

Comment: @Lambie, esses exemplos que apresentaste soam muito mal em português de Portugal. Talvez em brasileiro seja perfeitamente normal, mas isso já não sei.

Comment: Pois (como se diz na sua terra), apresenta outros. A tarefa não foi exatamente distinguir as variantes do português. Acho que há tendência de exagerar tudo isso. Em todo caso, nado disso muda as três traduçoes que dei. Não usei nenhuma expressão marcada a não ser a forma verbal: /Você só está chegando agora/ Eis a tradução só para ti: Tu só estás a chegar agora?

Comment: As duas outras frases ficariam igualzinhas. E você nem respondeu a minha pregunta. Eu até mostrei que a sua frase sairia come eu falei. Então, acho que e assunto morreu (como se diz no Brasil) para mim.

Answer (score 0):

I tell my students that it means the same as *at this point of the race*. If the context can be metaphorized as a race, then this expression could be used adequately.

Now, if your students have as many issues with metaphors as mine do, tell them a race is a process that has a start, a finish (that is approaching quickly), and a history. It is too late to give up, so some corners need to be cut in order to achieve the best results available.

Comment: Well, it's not a race. It's usually a game (as in a championship game).

Comment: Ramon, if I were a non-native speaker  your answer wouldn't help me understand the diference between "a essa altura do campeonato", "agora", and "neste exato momento".

Comment: I've edited the question and tried to make clear what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The expression conveys either a neutral feeling, when referring to (most usually) a later stage of an implicit period (examples below), or a feeling of resignation (or, less commonly, frustration or even despair) face a situation that can't anymore be changed because it's too late. The best translation then is often `by now`, `by then`.

It's a rather informal expression, that's used for **emphasis**.

Some usage examples:

- the literal one: "Nessa altura do campeonato o time não tem mais chances de chegar à final."
- ="in this/that stage/moment": "Nessa altura do campeonato você já deveria ter aprendido isso."; "Naquela altura do campeonato, eu já não conseguia me aguentar em pé."
- ="after everything [that happened]": "Nessa altura do campeonato não tenho mais vontade de voltar com ela."
- ="too late [for doing something]": Nessa altura do campeonato não temos mais como contactá-lo."
- [Less often] ="at this stage" (any, also early): "Nessa altura do campeonato não dá ainda para saber quem é o culpado."

A situation where its usage is ruled out is when referring to an exact point in time, rather than a stage: "Naquela altura do campeonato ela abriu a porta." is unlikely to work in most natural contexts.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's best to start by translating it into each different context. Instead, you can explain that it's an emphatic expression that more literally means "now", that is, "at this present time" or "in this current situation". Then, you can explain the contexts where it tends to be used, and the nuances of what it's understood to mean in those contexts.

To give a parallel example (because I'm not super familiar with that phrase), you *could* teach "muito" as having different meanings of "a lot" and "too much". (That's what ordinary dictionaries do.) But I prefer the explanation that while still having the meaning "a lot", it can have a *connotation* of "too much", just like an emphasized "A LOT!" can.

Comment: I've edited the question and tried to make clear what I'm looking for.